# XML-RPC: How to add media caption to uploaded image?

Tags: uploads, media, xml-rpc, captions

I need to migrate non-WP data from an SQL database to posts in WP, and thought that using XML-RPC in a closed environment before deploying was a smart solution.

This is my first WP project, so I'm still quite new to WP.

I've managed to upload the images XML-RPC. Unfortunately, I can't see that neither metaWeblog.newMediaObject nor wp.uploadFile supports caption, alt or description fields.

I tried uploading the image and then edit the post with the ID returned from the upload. The wp.editPost returns a boolean set to true, which makes me believe the changes were set. But when I check the media library, the image caption fields are still empty.

Does anyone have any suggestions what I should do?

Comment: Read this -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Caption_Shortcode

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it's not a valid solution as the images are to be stored in custom fields and not as shortcodes in the body text.

Comment: So I finally found a clue. The media article type stores the caption in post_excerpt, description in post_content. I'm not quite sure which field stores the alt text, but I'm quite happy with just storing the caption in post_excerpt.

Comment: Were you able to find a way to create the caption while using `wp.uploadFile`? I'm stuck in this same boat too and fear that I may have to make a separate call to update the image post after the image has been uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found a clue. The media article type stores the caption in post_excerpt, description in post_content. I'm not quite sure which field stores the alt text, but I'm quite happy with just storing the caption in post_excerpt.